# Abstract class to get rid of redundant code in activities

Tags: java, android, oop, android-activity, abstract-class

I created an abstract class to prevent redundant code in each of my activities.

```
public abstract class MyGeneralizedActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }
      //...
 }
```

I was perfectly fine by doing this:

```
public class MyActivity extends MyGeneralizedActivity{...}
```

But now I got to the point where I have to extend `MyActivity` from `FragmentActivity`. That means I can't extend from `MyGeneralizedActivity` anymore.

Now I am wondering if it's possible to set up a general abstract structure to extend all of my activities.

**EDIT**
Just by extending `MyGeneralizedActivity` from `FragmentActivity` won't solve my problem. e.g. `TabActivity` will lead to the same issue.

**UPDATE**
For those who may be interested in solving the same problem in Android I've found a simple workaround. There exist the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class, which provides, among other things, the interface [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). It does exactly what I need allowing us to intercept and add some value into important events for all activities.

All you have to do is to extend the Android `Application` Class and create a private class within which implements `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.
Don't forget to add/rename your Application in your `AndroidManifests` file:

```
<application
     android:name=".application.MyApplication" 
     //...
/>
```

Comment: You can create a interface with default method if using Java 8. Then you can implement multiple interfaces this way and get desired result.

Comment: Given [`FragmentActivity` is itself a subclass of `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), is there any reason you can't just make `MyGeneralizedActivity extends FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: Why aren't you extending from AppCompatActivity? Also, just curious, what requirement do you have for FragmentActivity?

Comment: @PPartisan edited my main post.

Comment: This is why composition is favored over inheritance. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11343840/3474528

Answer (score 1):

As both `FragmentActivity` and `MyGeneralizedActivity` are classes and not interfaces there is no way to create a type that is a subtype of both.

Java limits you to single inheritance, so if you're dependent on sharing implementation that's included in two classes, your best bet here is relying on composition instead.

For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity { 
  FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
  MyGeneralizedActivity myGeneralizedActivity;

  public MyActivity(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, MyGeneralizedActivity myGeneralizedActivity) {
    this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
    this.myGeneralizedActivity = myGeneralizedActivity;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.fragmentActivity.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.myGeneralizedActivity.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //...
  }

  @Overridepublic void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    this.fragmentActivity.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    this.myGeneralizedActivity.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    //...
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you can overload an `Activity` class's constructor in this way.

Comment: Upon closer inspection `Activity`, does have a default constructor, so you should be able to instantiate a subtype of `Activity` exactly as I've proposed unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm thinking of the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28636652/1219389) question (and a few [others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8555673/1219389)), which specify all `Activity` classes use their default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a problem for the [Decorator Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator).

## Intent

- Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality.
- Client-specified embellishment of a core object by recursively wrapping it.
- Wrapping a gift, putting it in a box, and wrapping the box.

## Problem

You want to add behavior or state to individual objects at run-time. Inheritance is not feasible because it is static and applies to an entire class.

## Structure

The canonical form:
[image: Decorator Pattern Diagram]

Thinking specifically about your case, since Android API does not define an interface for Activity, we could skip some bureaucracy and just do it in the (not so) quick and dirty way:

```
abstract public class ActivityDecorator extends Activity {
    protected Activity original;

    public MyAcitvityDecorator(Activity original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.original.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /* ... Because there is no better way of doing it in Java, you should do
     * this for every method in the Activity class: delegate the execution of 
     * the method to the original activity object.
     * Yes, there is A LOT of methods!
}
```

Then you must create a concrete decorator and override the due methods:

```
class MyActivityDecorator extends ActivityDecorator {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            this.original.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
            this.original.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
        }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Activity myActivity = new MyActivityDecorator(new Activity());
```

Because `MyAcitvityDecorator` is an instance of `Activity`, you can pass it around seemlessly.

You could even chain decorators and change the original `Activity` object like this:

```
Activity myActivity = new MyActivityDecorator(
    new AnotherActivityDecorator(
        new TabActivity()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

See in [FragmentActivity source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java). `FragmentActivity` extends `Activity` class. I think you should try and see.

> Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a interface with default method if using Java 8. Then you can implement multiple interfaces this way and get desired result.

Refer for details: [Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19998454/1791492)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this proposal?  Ideally provide an example.    While it is true that it is possible to create a default implementation for interfaces in Java 8 there are limitations (e.g. you don't have access to instance state) so this is not necessarily a solution.